# Apache JMeter error when running a test from CMD

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm trying to run a JMeter test script from the CMD prompt but I keep getting this error:

An error occurred: The file C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.5\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin\templates\LoginPage.jmx -l C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Results\Jmeter.csv -e -o C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Results\report.csv doesn't exist or can't be opened

This is the command I'm running:

C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.5\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin>jmeter -n -t "C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.5\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin\templates\LoginPage.jmx -l "C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Results\Jmeter.csv" -e -o "C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Results\report.csv"

I'm just testing it out so ignore the folder location etc

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem:

```
C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.5\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin>jmeter 
                                                                ^ ka-boom
```

you need to change the `>` to `\` and the command should start working as expected

Full commmand just in case:

```
C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.5\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin\jmeter -n -t "C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.5\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin\templates\LoginPage.jmx" -l "C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Results\Jmeter.csv" -e -o "C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Results\report.csv"
```

More information:

- [How Do I Run JMeter in Non-GUI Mode?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)
- [Generating Reports](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report)

Comment: the > is just the the end of the directory of where I am in the CMD window so it can't be removed @Dmitri T

Comment: Also pay attention to the quotation mark after `LoginPage.jmx`

Answer (score 0):

This is the command you provided:

```
C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.5\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin>jmeter -n -t "C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.5\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin\templates\LoginPage.jmx -l "C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Results\Jmeter.csv" -e -o "C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Results\report.csv"
```

If we break it up into multiple lines and strip off the prompt, for clarity, we get:

```
jmeter ^
    -n ^
    -t "C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.5\apache-jmeter-5.5\bin\templates\LoginPage.jmx ^
    -l "C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Results\Jmeter.csv" ^
    -e ^
    -o "C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Results\report.csv"
```

You will notice that the filename passed after `-t` is missing a quote at the end.